# Which build agent did my build?

Tags: tfs, msbuild

Can I determine which of my multiple build agents did the job for me after the build is done? The report does not tell me that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click on "View Log" at the top of the report it will tell you.

There will be a line similar to this one in the first few lines of your Log (unless you have verbosity turned up).

> Run On Agent (reserved build agent XXXX)

Comment: Is it possible to specify in my build definition which agent I want to use?

Comment: Yes, Process > Advanced > Agent Settings > Name Filter. In future, feel free to raise a new Question, you'll probably get a quicker answer.